# iPhone Strange CoreData Caching Performance Issues

Tags: iphone, performance, caching, core-data

I'm working on an app that uses Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController. A major component of the app is the filtering down items in an indexed table view based on a set of 15 or so pre-defined switches that correspond to a property or relationship of my Managed Objects. In most of my situations, I'm searching through a set of around 300-400 objects, so caching/performance is not an issue. Everything is very snappy with no caching required.

However, there is a part of my app that basically searches through all objects in my CD database (~15,000 items). Here, I'm trying to implement caching on the NSFetchedResultsController to improve performance. The 'cacheString' property for the NSFetchedResultsController is simply the predicate's string value. Whenever the user toggles a filter switch, I create a new predicate, create a new NSFetchedResultsController, and set the cache to the new predicate's string value. The first hit to get all the items (unfiltered) takes ~7 seconds, with subsequent hits taking less than one.

What's strange, though - and here's my problem - is that once I proceed to the 'next step' of the table view (I push a new view controller to the nav controller, passing it a reference to the NSFetchedResultsController's fetchedObjects), performance drops considerably. This next view is essentially a different representation (a horizontally paging scroll view) of the previous view's table list with one item on the screen at once. When I page from one item to the next, accessing the previous or next object in the fetchedObjects array locks up the phone for about 5 seconds. The 'lock up' duration increases the further you go into the fetchedObjects array. If 'i == 0', there is no perceivable lag. If 'i == 10,000', it takes about 15 seconds to access the next object. Nuts! If I disable caching (or it's a query that wasn't cached so it needed to pull fresh results), everything except for the initial filter query is fast and snappy with zero lag.

Does enabling caching ONLY cache indexing info for a table view and not the fetched objects themselves?

I'm not sure what the deal is here. I hope I explained this well enough - let me know if you want to see some code or need additional info.

Thanks!
Billy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I've found out what my problem was...

Basically, asking my NSFetchedResultsController for a managedObject via objectAtIndexPath: is IMMENSELY faster than going directly to the fetchedObjects array and asking for objectAtIndex: (which, of course, is what I was doing), especially as your index gets into the thousands. I'm not sure 100% why that is, though. I'm guessing NSFetchedResultsController does some fancy stuff to efficiently pull out single objects rather than going straight to the raw data. So, I don't think the caching had anything to do with my performance issue.

Thanks to those who checked out my question. I hope this helps anyone else having similar issues.